# How do I can get a value from a table from HTML to VBA

Tags: html, excel, vba

I'm trying to get a certain value from a web page but all that I try doesn't work. My HTML code is:

```
<tr class="TRLinha1">
<td class="TDTitulo">Adv. Funcionário</td>
<td class="TDLinha2"><span id="C2">Fulano De tal </span></td>
<td class="TDTitulo">Adv. Credenciado</td>
<td class="TDLinha2"><span id="C3">Escritorio Identidade</span></td>
<td class="TDTitulo" colspan="2">
    <img id="imgAdvogadoCredenciado" onclick="fcnShowAdvogadoCredenciado(1)" onmouseover="this.style.cursor='hand'" src="../../../../../../../Portal/Imagens/arquivo.png" alt="Exibir Advogado Credenciado" style="border-width:0px;">
</td>
```

The value that I'm trying to get is the one with id = "C2"--> Fulano De tal. Then I will set this value in a cell. I already have the VBA code to log in the current web page.

Can anyone help me?

this is my VBA code:

```
    Sub FazerLoginSite()
Dim IE As Object
Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.application")
Dim node, nodeList

NumeroPasta = InputBox("Pasta")

With IE
.Visible = True
.Navigate ("https:mywebsite")
While .Busy Or .ReadyState <> 4: DoEvents: Wend
On Error Resume Next
.document.getElementById("username").Focus
.document.getElementById("username").Value = "login"
.document.getElementById("password").Focus
.document.getElementById("password").Value = "password"
.document.All("button1").Click
On Error GoTo 0
While .Busy Or .ReadyState <> 4: DoEvents: Wend

While .Busy Or .ReadyState <> 4: DoEvents: Wend
.document.getElementById("pasta").Focus
.document.getElementById("pasta").Value = NumeroPasta
While .Busy Or .ReadyState <> 4: DoEvents: Wend

While .Busy Or .ReadyState <> 4: DoEvents: Wend
    IE.document.parentWindow.execScript "localizar();", "javascript"
While .Busy Or .ReadyState <> 4: DoEvents: Wend

' here is where i suppose to have a code that get the desire value



End With
End Sub
```

Comment: What code have you written so far?

Comment: Can you show how you tried the code I posted?  You need to assign the return value to something: it does not stand by itself...

Answer (score 0):

This answer requires a basic knowledge of Internet development technologies. 
I guess that to understand the answer, you should read a little. I've included links.

You have 2 options:
1. Use html form and put the value into a input field.

```html
<form action="YOUR_HANDLER" method="post">
  <table>
    <tr class="TRLinha1">
      <td class="TDTitulo">Adv. Funcionário</td>
      <td class="TDLinha2"><input type="text" id="C2" value="Fulano De tal" /></td>
      <td class="TDTitulo">Adv. Credenciado</td>
      <td class="TDLinha2"><span id="C3">Escritorio Identidade</span></td>
      <td class="TDTitulo" colspan="2">
        <img id="imgAdvogadoCredenciado" onclick="fcnShowAdvogadoCredenciado(1)" onmouseover="this.style.cursor='hand'" src="../../../../../../../Portal/Imagens/arquivo.png" alt="Exibir Advogado Credenciado" style="border-width:0px;">
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</form>
```

http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_forms.asp

2. Using AJAX. With ajax you can send data to your server without using a html form.

http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/

Comment: I'm doing all this code with Microsoft Excel, VBA. If you want I can show my vba code, but I don't think this will help anyway. I have a code that log in and open the web page that I want, them I need to get a value from a table in html

Comment: I'm a little confused. The excel is generate the html code?

Comment: @MoshFeu - He's trying to extract a value from an _external_ webpage using VBA.

Comment: Still don't understand.. What the communication (or the relationship) between the html file and the excel file? If you can, I'd love to get the full picture

Comment: @MoshFeu - That's what he needs to show. He's probably automating Internet Explorer.

Comment: What is "That"? Is this a website that users can view some data? Doe's he need to submit data from the web page and save it into the excel? I'm beginning to despair of understanding the question.

Comment: @MoshFeu - It's pretty simple. He wants to load a website, login, extract a value from resulting page, and return it to Excel.

Answer (score 0):

```
IE.document.getElementById("C2").innerText
```

should give you what you need

Comment: When I add this code excel say that this object do not support this method

Comment: How do I add another code in my original question instead add an "answer your question"?

Comment: Click the "edit" link under your question and paste in your code.  Use the "code bock" button to format it.

Comment: With IE
While .Busy Or .ReadyState <> 4: DoEvents: Wend
    Cells(1, 1) = IE.document.getElementById("C2").innerText
While .Busy Or .ReadyState <> 4: DoEvents: Wend

Comment: And it takes the erro of execution 91 -- A variable of object or a variable of wtih blocks not defined

Comment: That error indicates there's no element with id C2 in the document

Comment: but you saw my HTML code, and there is an element with id C2

Comment: Yes, I did, and that's why I suggested that approach. Given the information provided, it should work.  If it's not working then it's difficult to suggest why not without a URL to test with.

Comment: I don't know much of HTML but, this Id is inside a span, doesn't that make any difference?

Comment: No, that shouldn't impact anything.

Comment: what if I want to get everything in with <td> hipertext?

Comment: You can use `getElementsByTagName("td")` and it will return a collection of td elements: you'd have to loop over that to find the item you want.

Comment: Ok man, I won't take your time. I tried that last code u said, but seems nothin works. I appreciate your help. Really

Answer (score 0):

You could try using `split` on the `document.innerHTML` to get that string i.e.

```
Split(Split(.document.innerHTML, "id=""C2"">")(1), " <")(0)
```